# Create a custom circular progress bar

Tags: android, android-view, android-support-library, android-progressbar

I want to create a custom circular progress bar that should look like this:

[image]

But I dont want to use a library and it needs to support api level 9 and above. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set you image in an `ImageView` and do this.

```
loadingIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_loader);
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(500);
loadingIcon.startAnimation(anim);
```

When you need to stop it do this

```
loadingIcon.setAnimation(null);
```

NOTE: If you need to use it at multiple places then create a custom View which extends `ImageView` with this code and use anywhere you want.

Comment: I cant get this to work, should I set a backround to the imageview?

Comment: ..and for my previous comment, that was the answer

Comment: does your image rotate like a progress bar? If yes then its up to you how you want to customize it.